# is there a solution for NoSuch Element Exception

Tags: java

i face this exception, how can i solve it

```
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at javafxapplication2.Main.start(Main.java:368)
```

This is my code implemintation:

```
       Scanner input = null;

        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("src/javafxapplication2/grid10x10.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          String sizeString = input.next();       //get the size as a string
          size = Integer.parseInt(sizeString);
      input.next();


          /*Now read the vertices*/
          for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
          {
              veNum = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                x = input.nextInt();
                y = input.nextInt();

              vertices[i] = new Vertex(veNum, x, y);
          }




          /*Now read the edges */
          while(input.hasNext())
          {
              int vertex1 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
              int vertex2 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());




              addEdge(vertex1, vertex2, distance);  


          }
```

this is my txtfile
this is my txtfile
https://github.com/ieee8023/cs210-summer2014/blob/master/project2/grid10x10.txt

thank's of all again

Answer (score 1):

check `input.hasNextInt()` before using `nextInt()`

```
if(input.hasNextInt()) 
{
   x = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: check before each `nextInt`